# How do I stop the default folders from being reset if they're in an SSHFS location?

Tags: 10.04, sshfs

Last time I was on my laptop I set the default folders for Ubuntu to directories on another computer with SSHFS, but every time I restart my laptop, it just resets everything to `/home/thomas` (since I've deleted the respective directories on my laptop). I'm assuming this is because it starts SSHFS in the fstab after it loads the locations to the default folders. How can I fix this?

These are the default folders I'm referring to, by the way:
[image]

They get reset back to `/home/thomas` after being set to folders in the directory mounted for SSHFS, `/home/thomas/Files/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to relocate the Documents, Pictures, etc. directories, you can use xdg-user-dirs-update.  The syntax is `xdg-user-dirs-update --set TYPE /path/to/directory`.  Type is one of "DESKTOP DOWNLOAD TEMPLATES DOCUMENTS MUSIC PICTURES VIDEOS PUBLICSHARE".  The configuration is stored in ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs.  If you manually edit that file, changes will take effect after a restart.

(Old answer preserved for the record.)
If you're mounting the home directory somewhere other than /home/thomas, you can use usermod to tell the system to look for your home directory elsewhere:

```
usermod -d /sshfs/thomas thomas
```

Substitute /sshfs/thomas with where the sshfs home directory is being mounted.

Comment: The home directory isn't being mounted in a different location, but the folders that would normally be in it are (excluding all of the hidden application config folders).

Comment: I've tested the revised version above on a virtual machine and it worked for me.  In my testing, the SSHFS was always mounted before I logged in to the desktop, and it did not get set back to anything else.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, but every time I restart, it looks for the `/path/to/directory/` before it mounts it for SSHFS. Therefore, it can't find the directory and resets it back to `/home/thomas`

Comment: Yep, @David, I just restarted and they're all set to `/home/thomas` again.

Comment: It shouldn't look for those paths until you login.  Is the SSHFS being started automatically on boot?  Do you have automatic login turned on?

Comment: My bad, no, SSHFS isn't started on boot. I have it set to start in Startup Applications preferences window. I was too lazy to set it up to do AutoFS.

Comment: I've marked your answer as accepted and will give you the bounty when I can. This is a problem due to me being lazy and not setting it to mount automatically the proper way. And I've only continued to be lazy by setting a script that ran the command you listed above for every type after I login.

But thanks for your help!